# Could not find artifact org.wildfly.core:wildfly-coer-parent:pom:myVersion in jboss-public-repository-group

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I am using Maven for my project. I have a parent project myProjectA and when I do mvn clean install it builds successfully. myProjectA has multiple children, one of which is "childA1". This childA1 calls a plugin childB1 from myProjectB.

The problem is that when I try to do mvn clean install on childA1 then it fails with error:

`Plugin my-maven-plugin:0.1-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for my-maven-plugin:jar:0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.wildfly.core:wildfly-core-parent:pom:myVersion in http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of jboss-public-repository-group has elapsed or updates are forced`

I understand from the error that the dependency org.wildfly.core in my-maven-plugin is not found. This dependency does not appear explicitly in the pom of childA1 or childB1. So to try to solve my problem I added the dependency to childB1 and did mvn clean install on childB1, the dependency was resolved and build was successful. While doing this I saw that the dependency was in fact downloaded from `http://mynexus/nexus/content/groups/public` and not the jboss repository that childA1 tries to get it from.

I looked at the "effective pom" tab (in Eclipse) of childA1 and childB1 and there I saw that the correct repository, mynexus, was listed and not the jboss repository.

Other things I tried is running with -U and I made sure to build myProjectA before building childA1. Unfortunately this did not solve my problem. Any suggestions how to fix it are welcome.

Comment: Sounds like your childB1 has a mirror defined for the jboss public repo that specifies to use your nexus instead. Check whether your childB1 build uses a different profile, a different settings.xml, or if its pom.xml contains a `distributionManagement` section

Comment: Thanks for the respone, I checked it. The settings.xml is the same one for all, the pom.xml distributionManagement section is also the same. ChildA1 can use a different profile but I'm currently not using that. Another thing I found is that the mentioned dependency in the error message is not even a dependency in childA1, childB1, myProjectA, or myProjectB. So I don't know why it is trying to find it.